# Why haven't the Sith tried to harvest midichlorian?

Tags: star-wars, sith

Seeing as midichlorians are found in all life in varying levels, it's conceivable that a Sith Lord could harness their resources to discover a way to do this and subsequently add it to their bodies.  If midichlorian count is important as a ratio of power of the Force, then it stands to reason the higher the count the better and thus makes the perfect incentive for a Sith Lord to harvest and incorporate midichlorians into their own body.

But why haven't they?  Or why haven't we heard of this?

Comment: http://darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0086.html

Comment: I'm specifically referring to why the Sith haven't done this.

Comment: Technically, the other questions asks if such a thing would work, but as the answers explain, it *doesn't* work - which also explains why the Sith haven't done it. The other answers also explain that there *have* been attempts by the Sith to infuse non-Force-Users with Midichlorians, to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Midi-chlorian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian) counts did not indicate an upper limit to Force ability; the possibility existed for a Jedi to achieve a connection to the Force on an equivalent level to a Jedi with a higher count.<sup>1</sup>

It was attempted however, in the final novel of the Clone Wars story arc, "[Yoda: Dark Rendezvous](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda:_Dark_Rendezvous)," we learn that there was forbidden experimentation on midi-clorians conducted by the Nobles on the Sith refuge of [Vjun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vjun) in an attempt to increase force sensitivity. Their experiments were unsuccessful, and drove the entire population of Vjun mad.

There were Sith who were successful with [Midi-chlorian manipulation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian_manipulation). Emperor Palpatine's Sith Master, [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis), was a master of midi-chlorian manipulation to the degree that he could heal himself when wounded, prevent himself from aging, restore life to the dead, and even cause animals to give birth without a partner. It was Plagueis experiments with the midi-chlorians that caused the immaculate conception of Anakin Skywalker. Plagueis tried to create a being out of the midi-chlorians, but assumed he had failed, but what had actually happened was the Force itself responded to the attempt by creating *the one* who would destroy the Sith.

It is possible that the Sith could have eventually found a successful method of harvesting midi-chlorians to inrease their force sensitivity–the immortal Plagueis would probably have eventually figured it out if Palpatine hadn't killed him–but after the creation of the Empire, all research on midi-chlorians was made illegal.

---

<sup>1. [wookieepedia: Midi-chlorian Biology](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian#Biology).</sup>

<sup>**Random fact:** *midi-chlorians are real!* (see [Midichloria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midichloria) on Wikipedia). It's a recently discovered organism that was found inside the mitochondria of cells. The scientist that discovered it asked George Lucas for permission to name it midi-chlorian and Lucas consented.</sup>